# Fast (low-footprint) javascript clock

Tags: javascript, optimization, memory, time

I'm trying to create a live clock based on javascript.

The important part is that it keeps a low memory footprint, meanwhile staying accurate at the same time.

This is my code:

```
<div id="time">...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // I'm actually using a better name for such a global variable.
    // Here I'm presuming a lookup in a global variable is faster than to a local one
    var weekdays={"0":"Sun","1":"Mon","2":"Tue","3":"Wed","4":"Thur","5":"Fri","6":"Sat"};

    function refTime(){
      // get current time stamp
      var date=new Date();
      // add an hour so we get UTC+1
      date.setUTCHours(date.getUTCHours()+1) // UTC+1
      // store time components separately
      var day=date.getUTCDay(),
          hrs=date.getUTCHours(),
          min=date.getUTCMinutes(),
          sec=date.getUTCSeconds(),
          mer=false;
      // find meridiem and reduce 24h to 12h
      hrs=(mer=hrs<12) ? hrs : hrs-12;
      // generate the markup
      document.getElementById('time').innerHTML
        =weekdays[day]+'<br/>'+day+'<br/>'
        +(hrs<10?'0':'')+hrs+':'+(min<10?'0':'')+min+':'
        +(sec<10?'0':'')+sec+' '+(mer ? 'am' : 'pm');
    } // end format is: "Tue<br/>19<br/>11:43:25 am"
    setInterval(refTime,1000);

</script>
```

Can it be further optimized?

Notes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/date

Comment: A couple of issues: first, you probably want to use `setInterval`, rather than `setTimeout`, since the latter ensures that your code is only called once. Then, in the call to setTimeout/setInterval, you need to drop the capital 'T' in `refTime`, as the original function is called `reftime`.

Comment: Where to do have any memory concerns? This code will hardly use any significant memory as it is. However there are several bugs: displayed time and am/pm for midnight and noon will be wrong, and the clock will only update once, when the page is loaded.

Comment: Well, yeah, must admit I wrote it on the top of my mind :). My concern is with all that conditional/computational stuff in that function.

Comment: RoToRa - I'm allocating a new Date instance every second. Any memory leak may easily build up. So far it looks ok (I've watched vmem in recent browsers). But browsers are kind of unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use one of the Date toYYYString() methods and String.split() to get the appropriate fields.

What's so special about UTC+1? If the user is in North America or Asia, they'll still want UTC+1?

You could detect the browser and handle the couple of different date formats. Different broser Date.toYYYString() method results: http://home.clara.net/shotover/datetest.htm

Comment: UTC+1 is the timezone of where the website resides in. That is, the clock is showing the local time of this particular country. I also gave those formats a couple of looks, but I'm afraid they're too diverse from what I need to be usable.